# concatenate columns with - in sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am having Table

```
id1     id2 
----   ----
2       16
null    11
1       01
10      32
```

now i want to concatenate these two columns with '-'

```
 id
 ----
 2-16
 11
 1-01
 10-32
```

i tried this with simple concat() func

```
select concat(id1,'-',id2)[id]
```

it results,

```
 id
 ---
 2-16
 -11//need only 11 not -11
 1-01
 10-32
```

then tried with concat_ws() but it was not a function in sql server 2008.
then with COALESCE() but it results the same.

it can be done using condition statement.

but is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using NVL function in Oracle. I think equivalent function in sqlserver is ISNULL

SELECT nvl(id1, '') ||  '-' || nvl(id2, '')
from table;

Comment: Thanks. But nvl is not a built-in function in sql server 2008